# Creating symbolic link with programmatic name

Tags: ansible

How would one create symbolic links in Ansible with programmatic names?

I need this for LDAP. Command I usually run is this:

```
ln -s /etc/openldap/cacerts/mycert.pem /etc/openldap/cacerts/`openssl x509 -noout -hash -in /etc/openldap/cacerts/mycert.pem`.0
```

The command module does not accept such command, it will say

```
"stderr": "ln: invalid option -- 'o'\nTry 'ln --help' for more information."
```

And the file module which is meant for this does not seem to support adding some shell commands at all. What could be done in Ansible to solve such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using shell module:

```
shell: ln -s /etc/openldap/cacerts/mycert.pem /etc/openldap/cacerts/`openssl x509 -noout -hash -in /etc/openldap/cacerts/mycert.pem`.0
```

Comment: Seems to work. Ansible logs are warning me on every run but this will do for now.